# How to convert <select> with optgroup into JSON array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

HTML:

```
<select multiple size="10" class="show" id="boxA"></select>
<nav id="buttons">
    <ul class="small-block-grid-2 medium-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-2">
        <li><a class="remove" href="#">Remove</a></li>
        <li><a class="add" href="#">Add</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<select multiple size="10" class="show" id="boxB"> </select>
```

How to convert  `<select multiple size="10" class="show" id="boxB"> </select>`  into JSON array so that I can send it over to server via ajax?

For your information the select box with ID boxB created by PHP file with `<optgroup>.`

PHP file:

```
$last_category = "";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $levels = $row['level_name'];
    $levels_id = $row['level_id'];
    $subjects = $row['subject_name'];
    $subjects_id = $row['subject_id'];
    if ($last_category != $levels) {
        $last_category = $levels;
        echo '<optgroup label="' . $levels . '" class="' . $q .'">';
    }
    echo '<option value="' . $subjects_id . '">' . $subjects . '</option>';
    if ($last_category != $levels)
        echo '</optgroup>';
}
```

Comment: hey,, can you give us outputed html from php?

Comment: @oserk sure, I think u can refer to my site for better understanding of what I'm trying to do...http://vani.valse.com.my/test-site/index.php....whatever you see on second box(boxB) is the outputted html from php based on the selected made on checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var json = $(':input').serializeArray()
var string = JSON.stringify(json)
```

Comment: I tried and alerted but it applies for boxA. Is there a way I can serialize those in boxB only?

Comment: sure, you just use that selector,, like this: `$('#boxB :input').serialize()`

Comment: it chnages the behaviour altogether...maybe I'm wrong...can you suggest, what's the best way to send those data from boxB into server?

Comment: you need to add name tag to your boxB .. something like `<select multiple="" size="10" class="show" id="boxB" name="aa"></select>` .. get it,, jquery need that to serialize :)